# Typescript with rxjs

Tags: typescript, rxjs, es6-module-loader

Im currently working on a typescript project without any module loaders.

Now I am trying to integrate rxjs, in my project. But i get everytime the error `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`. Is it necessary to use a module loader, and if yes could u help me on setting it up? Im currently compiling the ts file with `tsc -w`

### Main.ts

```
const mock = of('Hello');
mock.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HM</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/hm-logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you adding rxjs to your project?

Comment: with npm, using version rxjs: 6.3.1

Comment: Looking at the npm documentation the node package seems to be specific for CommonJS usage. The CDN version seems to be defining a global rxjs object instead. You should be able to use that without any modules. https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @toskv I managed to integrate rxjs to typescript without any module loaders. To accomplish this I needed to take consideration to following steps:

### 1.Step

Add the cdn link to the root **HTML** (within the head tag) like follows:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.3.3/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

### 2.Step

Add a rxjs.d.ts file with a global variable:

```
declare var rxjs;
```

### 3.Step

Include the rxjs.d.ts file in the tsconfig.json file like:

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "rxjs.d.ts"
  ]
```

### 4.Step

Now you can use rxjs in your ts file like:

```
const { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } = rxjs;
const { map, filter, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

range(1, 200)
    .pipe(filter(x => x % 2 === 1), map(x => x + x))
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```